# Two times "may" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Is it possible to write "may" only once in a sentence? Which one the sentences above is suitable for writing?

> Android **may** affect the system in a good way and **may** help in obtaining new useful features.

Or

> Android **may** affect the system in a good way and help in obtaining new useful features.

Writing "may" one time makes the second sentence correct meaning like the first one?

Comment: You don't need the second *may*. It's parallelism. The *affect* and *help* serve as verbs in the same context and thus the first *may* is linked with the latter clause as well (with *and*)

Comment: This will take mentioning two verbs differently - *Android **may** affect the system in a good way and **is** one of the most popular OSes in the technology world.* Here, the verbs don't act in the same way and hence, this parallelism requires mentioning of two verbs separately though joined with *and*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sentence is related to the following two independent sentences:

> Android [ **may** affect the system in a good way ].
>   Android [ **may** help in obtaining new useful features ].

We can join these sentences together with *and* and then factor out repeated material:

> ​1. [ [ Android may affect the system ... ] and [ Android may help in obtaining ... features ] ].
>   ​2. Android [ [ may affect the system ... ] and [ may help in obtaining ... features ] ].
>   ​3. Android may [ [ affect the system ... ] and [ help in obtaining ... features ] ].

All of these sentences are grammatical.

To put it another way, we can talk about deleting repeated material:

> ​1. Android may affect the system ... and Android may help in obtaining ... features.
>   ​2. Android may affect the system ... and <s>Android</s> may help in obtaining ... features.
>   ​3. Android may affect the system ... and <s>Android</s> <s>may</s> help in obtaining ... features.

We can remove *Android* and *may* because they're repeated.

Comment: this rule is also suitable for **"have"**. Can I alter the following sentence "I **have** **completed** my paper and **have** **written** your name on it" like this: I **have** **completed** my work and **written** your name on it. @snailplane ?

Comment: @Hakan Yes, that's fine.